# LinkedList: Iterate and remove element

Tags: scala, iterator, iteration

In Scala, while iterating through the elements of a LinkedList, I would like to have some method remove() which removes the current element and (very important) makes the iterator point to the next element (or to the first if the current element is the last one; to null or something if there are no more elements).

Comment: Why would you? Perhaps you could explain what are the motives for such need?

Comment: I need to successively iterate through all the elements and pick one which is most suitable in each round. At some point, some elements become inactive, and I want to remove them from the list. I would like constant time for removal (hence linked list) and I also need to remember the position of the one that was picked in the last iteration. Do you have a better suggestion for a data structure?

Comment: do you have repetitive items or they are meant to be unique?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this what you want but how about:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def round(xs: Set[(Int, Int)]) = {
    // here you might check if items are exhausted and possibly don't go through recursion deeper


    val suitable = xs.filter {
        case (x, i) => 
            println("Element "+x+" on position "+i)
            x != 0
    }

    // do something with suitable items

    round(xs.diff(suitable)) // next round with items that doesn't succeed in current round
}

val list = List(3,4,5)
round(list.zipWithIndex.toSet)
```

Comment: But we aren't removing anything. This is equivalent in performance with going through all elements and checking for each whether the property still holds. I would like to remove at each step, because the list might be huge and at each step a huge number of elements might get inactive.

Comment: @user1377000 you actually removing: `round(xs.diff(suitable))` here I'm passing down to the next round only those values that was not suitable yet. suitable will be garbage collected. Think of `xs.diff(suitable)` as `xs minus suitable`.

Comment: Of, didn't see the diff. Sorry about that.