# Remove current element from LinkedList

Tags: scala, linked-list, iteration

In Scala: There appears to be no `remove()` method for `LinkedList`, for some reason I can't understand. There is one for `DoubleLinkedList` though, but I don;t need a double linked list.

Also, how could I set the `current` element to the first? And how do I know when it has reached the end (is it `null`?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [LinkedList: Iterate and remove element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762177/linkedlist-iterate-and-remove-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `current` element in `LinkedList`.

There are only 2 fields in `LinkedList`: `elem` (or `head`) for element and `next` (or `tail`) for `LinkedList`.

You can test if `LinkedList` is empty using `isEmpty`. Every `LinkedList` contains an empty `LinkedList` as it's deepest tail. See [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList) for ASCII illustration.

You can delete Nth element (if any) like this:

```
var current = myLinkedList.drop(n-2)
current.next = current.next.next
```

Example:

```
scala> val myList = LinkedList(1,2,3,4,5)
myList: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[Int] = LinkedList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> val current = myList.drop(1)
current: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[Int] = LinkedList(2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> current.next = current.next.next
current.next: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[Int] = LinkedList(4, 5)

scala> myList
res0: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[Int] = LinkedList(1, 2, 4, 5)
```

You can't delete first element this way, but you can just forget about it:

```
scala> var myList = LinkedList(1,2,3,4,5)
myList: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[Int] = LinkedList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> myList = myList.next
myList: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[Int] = LinkedList(2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: If I just do `current.next=sublist.next.next`, is the previous `current.next` deleted by the garbage collector straight away, or is there still a reference to it?

Comment: @user1377000 `current.next=sublist.next.next` - it's a typo. Should be `current.next=current.next.next`. You have deleted reference to old value of `current.next`. It was the only reference to this element in `myList`.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, is there a particular reason why you need a LinkedList over the standard List in Scala?

As warned in the scaladoc, you could easily end up in NPEs with LinkedList, whereas a List won't have this issue unless you actually introduce null values.

a List tail method is usually all you need. Please consider this approach first, and only resort to a specialized class if absolutely necessary.

Comment: I want constant time removal, that's why I am considering linked list